# How can I create this radial Date and Time picker in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, uidatepicker

I want to create a date and slot picker in iOS like the Meru cab mobile application on Android.

[image]

Can we create a control like that?

Comment: Yes we can, provided we have enough talent and time.

Comment: How? Can you help me out?